# Implementing asynchronous behaviour in Angular material2 Matstepper

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using Stepper component of Angular material2 with Angular4

Component1

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
<mat-step></mat-step>
<mat-step></mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>

<button class="buttonImg" id="buttonnxt" (click)="goForward(stepper)" 
type="button"></button>`

goForward(stepper) {

this.stepperCurrentIndex = stepper;

switch (this.stepperCurrentIndex) {
 case 0: {
   this.project0linking()
   //before project0linking() containing asynchronous call should 
   finish after that stepper.next should be called
   stepper.next();
   break;
 }
  case 1: {
    this.project1linking();
    //before project1linking() containing asynchronous call should 
    finish after that stepper.next should be called
    stepper.next();
    break;
     }
  case 2: {
    this.project2linking();
    //before project2linking() containing asynchronous call should 
    finish after that stepper.next should be called
    stepper.next();
    break;
      }
  }
}
```

Then another function containing http call is executed which is in another component, so I am able to get the response of http call in component1 but what can be done to execute stepper.next() method only after getting response of the http call

```
project0linking(){
 //http call
 Only after completion of this call stepper.next() should be called
}
```

I have tried passing "stepper" to another function but as it is an object of Stepper component and it has selectedIndex value and next() method it is not working.
Also tried hitting the library using **proto** to access next() in another function, was able to find the next() function but it accepts two paramters index and length of stepper which on passing it does accept throwing length of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Check the HttpClient at the documentation at [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http)

You can set a subscription to your requisition and call the stepper inside.

```
http.get('/api/items').subscribe(() => {
   stepper.next();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I can do stepper.next() but the issue is how can I have stepper the object which I am using in goforward(stepper) outside that function (as in is there a way by which I can place this stepper object as global)  and carry forward with next and previous state keeping intact , I am also using components within <mat-step> and in that component actually the http call is taking place so on completion of that event I need to execute next()